# Classifying space of a crossed complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Brown defines the classifying space of a crossed complex in the following way.

Given a filtration X<sub>*</sub> of a space X, define the fundamental crossed complex by:
C_0 = X_0, C_1=\pi(X_1,X_0) (the fundamental groupoid), C_n = the family of groups \pi(X_n,X_n-1,p) for all p in X_0.

Now let Δ^n be the cell complex of the standard n-simplex, with its skeletal filtration. The crossed complex \pi(π^n) is then written \pi[n]. The nerve NC of a crossed complex C is defined to be the simplicial set given in dimension n by (NC)n = Crs(\pi[n],C), where Crs(-,-) is the internal hom in the category of crossed complexes.

The think I don't understand is that each of the n-simplices are contractible, so why wouldn't the fundamental crossed complex associated to the filtration of Δ^n be trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed (weakly equivalent to) the trivial one, in the [model structure on crossed complexes](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/folk+model+structure).

Your question seems to indicate that you think this is a problem. But it is not: each cell of NC is contractible (as it is for each cell of a space!) but there may still be simplicial maps

partial Delta^n --> NC

from the simplicial set that is the boundary of the n-simplex into NC that represent non-trivial elements of [simplicial homotopy group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+homotopy+group)s of NC.

To see what is going on, in may be helpful to realize that the situation with crossed complexes is the analogue in the context of [*strict* oo-groupoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+omega-groupoid) of the more familiar situation with [Kan complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+complex)es.

A Kan complex is a model for a weak oo-groupoid. A crossed complex is a strict oo-groupoid (a more restrictive notion).

To any topological space X is associated its singular simplicial Kan complex S(X)  = Hom(Delta^bullet,X)-- which we may think of as the [fundamental weak oo-groupoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fundamental+infinity-groupoid) of X. This is the weak oo-groupoid version of Ronnie Brown's fundamental crossed complex.

Indeed, the nerve of Brown's fundamental crossed complex gives a Kan complex that approximates the full S(X).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the first hyperlink spills over the next lines. It doesn't in the source code. It doesn't in the preview. 

Comment: Urs: Just a couple of points. 1) Strict structures have an advantage for the calculations we have in mind,  in that one can for these usually work out how to calculate colimits. I am unsure how to make specific calculations with weak structures.  2) The  last sentence of your answer is true only under certain conditions on the filtered space $X_*$ with total space $X$. See Section 14.7 of "Nonabelian algebraic topology". Our fundamental crossed complex and the associated higher homotopy groupoids, are defined only for filtered spaces. 

Answer (score 2):

This is a belated reply to this, but I had no time to look at mathoverflow while finishing the book on "Nonabelian algebraic topology:..." .

First it should be emphasised that we get strict fundamental crossed complexes and $\infty$-groupoids (cubical or simplicial $T$-complex)  for filtered spaces, not for a "bare"  space. Indeed the fact that this strict theory works for filtered spaces, and so generalises the usual fundamental groupoid of a space with a set of base points, is part of the case for filtered spaces as a basic concept in algebraic topology. It will take time for this penny to drop!

The simplicial nerve of a crossed complex gives the usual nerve if the crossed complex is simply a groupoid in dimension 1.

The simplicial nerve of a crossed module is described in dimensions 1,2,3 on p. 323 of that book. See also the last part of section 3 of

`Groupoids and crossed objects in algebraic topology',
*Homology, homotopy and applications*, 1 (1999) 1-78.

for a crossed module $\mu: M \to P$ the nerve $K$ is given by:

$K_0 = {0}, K_1=P$. The 2-simplices of $K$ are quadruples
$k=(m;p,q,r)$ such that $m \in M, p,q,r \in P$ and $\mu m = q p r^{-1} $
with $\partial _0 k=p, \partial _1 k=r, \partial _2 k=q$.
The 3-simplices of $K$ are quadruples $(k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3)$ of 2-simplices
such that if
$k_i=(m_i;p_i,q_i,r_i), i=0,\ldots,3$, then
\begin{equation} m_0^{p_3} m_2 m_1^{-1} m_3^{-1} =1,
 \end{equation}and the edges of the
2-simplices $k_i$ match up to form a 3-simplex.
For $n\geqslant 4$, an $n$-simplex of $K$ is an $(n+1)$-tuple of
$(n-1)$-simplices of $K$, whose faces match up appropriately.

Actually in the reduced (one pointed) case this construction of the nerve of a crossed complex (but called a "group system") is essentially in

Blakers, A. Some relations between homology and homotopy groups.
*Ann. of Math*. (2) 49 (1948) 428--461.