# nerves of crossed complexes, group T-complexes and classifying spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff

A (reduced) [crossed complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+complex) is, intuitively, a non-abelian complex of groups $\ldots \to G_2 \to G_1 \to G_0$ with a $G_0$ action in such that $G_1 \to G_0$ is a crossed module.

There are a couple of constructions that could be called a classifying space of a crossed complex, namely the one given at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2734/classifying-space-of-a-crossed-complex), and the simplicial set arising from the  $\bar{W}$ functor applied to the simplicial group which is the [group T-complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+T-complex) associated to the crossed complex. (Aside: I would be tempted to call this the *groupal nerve*, as opposed to the simplicial set constructed in the process of forming the classifying space.) Then one can apply geometric realisation to get a space.

My question is this:

Does the usual classifying space functor from crossed complexes to topological spaces lift, up to homotopy, through the functor $|\bar{W} - |: sGrp \to Top$?

---

Edit: An equivalent formulation is this: for $T:Crs \to sGrp$ the functor from crossed complexes to simplicial groups in the above paragraph (this is half of the relevant Dold-Kan correspondence for crossed complexes), $N:Crs \to sSet$ the [nerve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2734/classifying-space-of-a-crossed-complex) functor and $\bar{W}:sGrp \to sSet$ the classifying space functor, do we have a (weak) homotopy equivalence
$$
\bar{W}T(G) \sim NG?
$$

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Ok - more details? Is it written down anywhere? This question came up in conversation with Andre Joyal, but I got stuck on this bit. My email is first.last@adelaide.e d u.a u if you would like it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following is related to your question:

Up to isomorphy, $\overline{\mathrm{W}}\colon \mathbf{sGrp} \rightarrow \mathbf{sSet}$ is the composite of the functors $\mathrm{N}\colon \mathbf{sGrp} \rightarrow \mathbf{s^2Set}$ and $\mathrm{Tot}\colon \mathbf{s^2Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{sSet}$, where $\mathbf{s^2Set}$ denotes the category of bisimplicial sets, where $\mathrm{N}$ denotes the nerve functor for simplicial groups (that is, nerve of groups, taken dimensionwise), and where $\mathrm{Tot}$ denotes the Artin-Mazur total simplicial set functor. On the other hand, one has the composite $\mathrm{Diag} \circ \mathrm{N}\colon \mathbf{sGrp} \rightarrow \mathbf{sSet}$, where $\mathrm{Diag}\colon \mathbf{s^2Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{sSet}$ denotes the diagonal simplicial set functor. Already $\mathrm{Tot} X$ and $\mathrm{Diag} X$ for a bisimplicial set $X$ are (naturally) weakly homotopy equivalent simplicial sets, see [1], so in particular $\overline{\mathrm{W}} G \cong \mathrm{Tot} \mathrm{N} G$ and $\mathrm{Diag} \mathrm{N} G$ for a simplicial group $G$ are weakly homotopy equivalent simplicial sets. In fact, $\overline{\mathrm{W}} G$ and $\mathrm{Diag} \mathrm{N} G$ for a simplicial group $G$ are (simplicially) homotopy equivalent simplicial sets, see [3]. For the isomorphism $\overline{\mathrm{W}} G \cong \mathrm{Tot} \mathrm{N} G$, see e.g. [2, rem. 4.19].

This could help for your question if your nerve functor $\mathbf{Crs} \rightarrow \mathbf{sSet}$ is (up to isomorphy? or at least up to natural weak homotopy?) the composite $\mathrm{Diag} \circ \mathrm{N} \circ \mathrm{T}$.

[1] Cegarra, A.M.; Remedios, J.: The relationship between the diagonal and the bar constructions on a bisimplicial set, Topology and its Applications 153(1) (2005), pp. 21-51. doi:10.1016/j.topol.2004.12.003

[2] Thomas, S.: (Co)homology of crossed modules, Diploma Thesis, RWTH Aachen, 2007. http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Sebastian.Thomas/publications/

[3] Thomas, S.: The functors Wbar and Diag Nerve are simplicially homotopy equivalent, Journal of Homotopy and Related Structures 3(1) (2008), pp. 359-378. http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Sebastian.Thomas/publications/

Comment: Just to check: are you defining the nerve of a group to be the nerve of the associated 1-object groupoid?

Comment: Yes. (Perhaps I use a non-standard convention numbering the morphisms in reverse order; that was to get the formulas of the simplicial operations $\overline{W} G$ as originally defined by Kan.)